# Implementar autenticación básica usuario y contraseña WCF SOAP

Tags: soap, wcf

en el momento me encuentro en la implementación de un servicio SOAP con WCF en el cual se necesita realizar la autenticación básica por usuario y contraseña usando basicHttpBinding he intentado varias implementaciones pero ninguna me ha dado resultado. Les agradecería sin alguien me puede dar una ayuda con el tema gracias.

web config

```
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="AutenticacionBasica">
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
    
        </bindings>
        <services>
            <service name="ServicioInicial.Service1">
                <endpoint 
                        address="https://localhost:44358/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                        bindingConfiguration="AutenticacionBasica"
                        contract="ServicioInicial.IService1" />
            </service>
        </services>
        
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior>
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                    <serviceAuthorization   serviceAuthorizationManagerType = "ServicioInicial.RestAuthorizationManager, ServicioInicial"/>
                    <!--<useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress />-->
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
```

Clase para realizar la validación de credenciales en este caso es la que encontré para realizar la operación de realizar la autorización una vez se valide que las credenciales de usuario y contraseña se encuentran correctas

```
public class RestAuthorizationManager : ServiceAuthorizationManager 
{
    /// <summary>  
    /// Method source sample taken from here: http://bit.ly/1hUa1LR  
    /// </summary>  
    protected override bool CheckAccessCore(OperationContext operationContext)
    {
        //Extract the Authorization header, and parse out the credentials converting the Base64 string:  
        var authHeader = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers["Authorization"];
        if ((authHeader != null) && (authHeader != string.Empty))
        {
            var svcCredentials = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII
                .GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authHeader.Substring(6)))
                .Split(':');
            var user = new
            {
                Name = svcCredentials[0],
                Password = svcCredentials[1]
            };
            if ((user.Name == "testuser" && user.Password == "testpassword"))
            {
                //User is authrized and originating call will proceed  
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                //not authorized  
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //No authorization header was provided, so challenge the client to provide before proceeding:  
            
            //Throw an exception with the associated HTTP status code equivalent to HTTP status 401  
            throw new WebFaultException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }
    }
}
```

Resultado final al tratar de ingresar al endpoint

**HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized**
No está autorizado a ver esta página; los encabezados de autenticación no son válidos.

El resultado que estoy esperando es que salga el cuadro de dialogo solicitando usuario y contraseña, seguidamente al dar clic en aceptar los datos viajen a la clase RestAuthorizationManager para poder realizar la validación.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Te recomiendo que agregues un [example] para que podamos entender tu problema. También agrega el error que estás teniendo. Cuando dices `he intentado varias implementaciones pero ninguna me ha dado resultado`. Cuál es el resultado que esperas?  Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y leas [ask] Por favor edita tu pregunta presionando en [edit].

Comment: Hola @AndresGardiol buenas tardes, en este caso el resultado que espero es que al ingresar al endpoint [enlace](https://localhost:44358/Service1.svc) me salga la ventana solicitando el usuario y contraseña, seguidamente al dar aceptar esos datos viajen a la clase RestAuthorizationManager

Comment: Por favor, todo detalle o aclaración agrégala a tu pregunta haciendo click en [edit]. Y todo mensaje de error que obtengas agrégalo como texto, no como imagen